# Laptop shutting down automatically - BIOS overheating

Tags: laptop, cpu, bios, shutdown, heatsink

My 4 year old laptop shuts down automatically with an error message **'The System has prevented from Bios overheating'** when try to restart the laptop.

It happens often and it was working for at least one hour. Nowadays it is not even alive for more than 10-30 secs from pressing the power button.

- Make & Model : HP G62
- Processor : Core i3
- RAM : 3 GB

Comment: mythbusters: "when in doubt, liquid nitrogen"

Comment: have you cleaned the dust out of the device and confirmed all fans are working?

Comment: Your laptop is overheating - how is the fan on that laptop? Is it faulty and has it been replaced?

Comment: Seems my fan working fine. before getting shutdown itself, the fan runs very fast

Comment: Have you tried walking into the laptop and looking at the fan? Check the heat sink - the thermal paste might also need replacing.

Comment: I have cleaned the processor area too

Comment: how to replace the thermal paste?

Comment: Thermal paste is just a pasty substance placed above the CPU to prevent overheating. The thermal paste may need to be 'pasted' on again. You can check this [http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Thermal-Paste] link which shows you how to apply thermal paste. But first you need to check if you have enough thermal paste already.

Comment: @zain.ali that link is only 10% of the battle that Krishna will face. The real issue will be figuring out how to take the laptop apart without breaking things. Also, the link is for a desktop cooler which could be misleading for Krishna

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as 'BIOS overheating' - what you're seeing is a badly worded message saying the BIOS has shut the system down to prevent CPU overheating.

From your symptoms the most likely problem is the contact between the CPU and the heatsink or a broken heatpipe. To confirm this, you'd expect to see cool or warm, but not hot air coming out of the exhaust vent even when the fan is running at full speed.

You'll need to replace the thermal paste between the processor and the heatsink, and if that doesn't solve it, the heatsink itself. Given you say you've cleaned the processor area I assume you've managed to take it apart, but if not, here's a starting point:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVpi4tJQL3w

Plenty more guides can be easily found:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=replace+thermal+paste+hp+g62